# Activity's savedInstanceState() not being called when going to new Activity via ActionBar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, textview, android-savedstate

Any Help would be appreciated because I am almost finished and this one little thing is bugging me so much!

I have 1 of three activities that in `onCreate()` it populates a `TextView` from a query of a database. This activity is also the main activity. The other 2 activities you travel through via the action Bar like the code below shows. I have both `savedInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` in play here and they only work when you exit out of the application completely, which is good but I also want it so that when you go to another Activity from the actionBar then the `TextView` Won't have to re-query the database. I want the `textview` to be the same as when you leave because every time you leave with the Actionbar the `textView` fires off a completely new query and I don't want that. I want it to still have the result of the first query when the user first arrived.

I tried using the `finish()` and the `onStop()` methods to help terminate the activity so that `saveOnInstanceState()` would be called when the Activity is destroyed but it either isn't working or I am not placing it in the right place. Any Thoughts Please?!?!?!

applying savedInstanceState in onCreate():

```
if(savedInstanceState != null){
        String SavedStory = savedInstanceState.getString(SavedStoryHere);
        String SavedTitle = savedInstanceState.getString(SavedTitleHere);
        OpenningTextView.setText(SavedStory);
        TitleTextView.setText(SavedTitle);
    }
    else{
        OpenningTextView.setText(StoryText);
        TitleTextView.setText(TitleString);
    }
```

The onSavedInstanceState() and the onRestoreInstanceState():

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    String text = OpenningTextView.getText().toString();
    String titleText = TitleTextView.getText().toString();
    savedInstanceState.putString(SavedStoryHere, text);
    savedInstanceState.putString(SavedTitleHere, titleText);
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    OpenningTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(SavedStoryHere));
    TitleTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(SavedTitleHere));        
}
```

Going to Different Activities via the ActionBar:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.Openning_Screen:
            Toast.makeText(this, "This is the Story of the Day", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
             .show();
            return true;
        case R.id.The_List:
            Intent A_ListIntent = new Intent(this, A_Where_List.class);
            startActivity(A_ListIntent);
            return true;
        case R.id.Settings:
            Intent SavedStoriesIntent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(SavedStoriesIntent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is your [Launch Mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) defined for your activities. By default it allows multiple instances, and in this case I think you want one instance. So when you "go back" to the original activity, it's a new instance and the onRestoreInstanceState() will not be called.

Try setting the launchMode to singleInstance for your activites in the manifest.

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is expected behaviour.

Calling `startActivity(intent)` does not finish/destroy your current Activity - that's why you're not getting `onSaveInstanceState` called. When the user presses the back button, your Activity will be in the state it was in when they left the page.

What you should be seeing is `onPause`/`onResume` called for leaving & re-entering your primary Activity.

Comment: Thanks for responding! so when I call `onPause()` or `onResume` (or both!) what would be the best way to save the values so I can have `onCreate` do with that container what it did with `onSavedInstanceState()`? SharedPreferences? just a regular list or String array?

Comment: `onPause` and `onResume` are called automatically for you. Looking at your code, you shouldn't have to do anything to have your text fields repopulated on Activity recreation. You can delete your `onRestoreInstanceState` method too - you're already handling everything in `onCreate`!

Comment: Note that I assume by this, you mean when you leave the Activity and then re-enter it by _pressing the back button_: "when you go to another Activity from the actionBar then the TextView will still be the same"

Comment: Im dumb.....I meant that the textView ISN'T the same when you go to another activity via the ActionBar....Im so sorry. I'll edit that right now